# golang struct method to take in multiple argument types

Tags: go

My method looks like:

```
func (t *Worker) updateInfo(n structType1, node structType2)
```

However, now i need to use this API to process both structType1 and structType3. Which means n could be structType3.

How do i modify the method to achieve this instead of writing another method like below and duplicate the same code?

```
func (t *Worker) updateInfo(n structType3, node structType2)
```

EDIT: These structs are all my own custom defined structs

Comment: What are these structs?   If they could implement an interface you could make your method take that interface.

Comment: Yes, they are all custom defined interfaces. @hookenz can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: https://gobyexample.com/interfaces

Comment: @drdot post the different struct definitions, that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **generics** in this case.

For instance, let's assume that `structType1` and `structType2` have a method called `Print`.

```golang
type  structType1 struct {}
func(st1 structType1) Print() {
 fmt.Println("Calling Print function of structType1")
}

type  structType2 struct {}
func(st3 structType3) Print() {
 fmt.Println("Calling Print function of structType2")
}
```

We can define interface type declarations as shown below.

```golang
type Struct13 interface {
 Print()
 structType1 | structType3 // type union 
}
```

Then you need to modify `Worker` struct and `updateInfo` function with type parameters. (Note: `Print` function in the `Struct13` is for demonstration purposes.)

```golang
type Worker[T Struct13] struct{}

func (t *Worker[T]) updateInfo(n T, node structType2) {
 n.Print()
}
```

We can use the above implementations as shown below.

```golang
    st1 := structType1{}
    st2 := structType2{}
    st3 := structType3{}


    w1 := Worker[structType1]{}
    w1.updateInfo(st1,st2)

    w2 := Worker[structType3]{}
    w2.updateInfo(st3,st2)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use empty interface

```
func (t *Worker) updateInfo(n interface{}, node structType2)
```

after go 1.18
you can use `any`

```
func (t *Worker) updateInfo(n any, node structType2)
```

and in the function body

```
switch v := n.(type) {
    case structType1:
        ...
    case structType3:
        ...
    default:
        ...
}
```